# Legacy web site project as 32 bit?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a web site project (not web application) project in visual studio that appears to be running as a 64 bit application at my hosting provider. Is there a way to tell or to configure the application to run as a 32 bit application?

Also -- since this is a web site project, doesn't the code get compiled on their servers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason your website needs to run as a 32-bit process?

Comment: @Dai  It's accessing Microsoft excel which appears to only be in 32 bit. The application is throwing this error: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. The hosting provider said that if I switched to 32bit mode that the error will no longer exist. They claim that my application pool is set to 32 bit mode.

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: @Dai The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: If your application pool is already running in 32-bit mode (as your webhost says) then the error means that the database driver isn't installed at all. You'll need to ask your webhost to install it on the server.

Comment: @Dai Thanks. That is what I figured the problem was...Either they really don't have me setup for 32bit or the office drivers are not installed on their machine. I just created an account with another hosting provider and uploaded the same exact app and it works as expected. I'm almost certain the issue is on their site. I will need to get in contact with them again. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the advance settings of the application pool, you can set "Enable 32-bit Applications". You could ask your hosting company if it's enabled.

In your solution, in the Configuration Manager. Make sure the platform is x86.

Comment: I only have the option to use AnyCpu in the configuration manager. How can I add x86?